# Flexible watermark in Photoshop for different image sizes

Tags: adobe-photoshop, resize, automation

I need help in making flexible watermark for different sizes image. means watermark scale or shrink as per image dimensions.

Something like this.
http://screencast.com/t/VnALAP2R6ff

Comment: Hi Ali, Welcome to GD.SE! I don't really understand your question or where you're having troubles. If you change the size of the image, then the watermark will automatically scale. Are you trying to do a full cover pattern watermark that will scale to fit the canvas size? Can you also tell us what you've tried and why that didn't work.

Comment: Hi Andrew, Thank you for your prompt response. I think I couldn't explain first time around so will try again here. If you look at the screen shot I sent, I'm trying to figure out  a way to keep the text size proportionate to image/canvas size. If the image is large, text is bigger, but for smaller image/canvas, text is automatically resized at the same proportion that it was originally when the canvas was bigger. Please note, that important thing is that text on this instance is a separate layer.

Comment: Are you scaling these images by resizing them or are you applying a new watermark for various sized documents? Because if you have a watermark on its own layer and then change the image size, the watermark will automatically scale. I am still not completely understanding what the issue is.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I would check out this tutorial. This might help.

https://youtu.be/2NRtn-BFMP0?list=PLqA0az417cgm3QoyOtZF-kLwahmOzs1Tl

Comment: Hi ErickP, can you write the core of what's behind the link in your answer? Link rotting is a problem, and if the video disappears in the future your answer will become useless. Besides, link-only and one-line answers are not encouraged here.

Comment: My apologies.  I'm a little tight for time today with work but I will try to write it out.  Just thought the link would provide a quick solution.

Answer (score 0):

Just add in a vector graphic of your watermark. Then you can scale to any size without ruining degrading the look and feel of the watermark